# How to place one PSD artboard in Illustrator 2018 as linked?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, artboard, import

I searched and googled but can't find anything on this. I want to place one artboard from a PSD into an Illustrator file. When I do, it shows all the artboards from the PSD file. I checked "import options" in Illustrator but it doesn't offer any options. Any ideas?

Comment: In this Adobe Help [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/importing-artwork-files.html#about_linked_and_embedded_artwork) see the "Place (import) artwork files" section

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do it, here are a couple of options:

If you hide the arboards in the PSD file (in Photoshop) using the eye icon in the layers panel, leaving only the one you want visible, and then save the PSD, then place it in Illustrator, it will only show the unhidden artboard. Obviously this isn't much use if you need more than one instance of the PSD for different artboards.

Another possibility is to simply place the PSD with all artboards visible in Illustrator, copy and paste it as many times as you need, once for each artboard, and use a clipping mask in Illustrator to isolate just one artboard for each copy.

For example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to link them together but it is possible to open psds in illustrator by converting them but this wont link the files.

You can read more on how to convert them [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/754514).

> "If you have the current version of photoshop and Illustrator then
>   just open the .psd version of the document in Illustrator and make
>   sure the 'Convert layers to objects' is selected and the image will
>   appear in Illustrator."